# MongoDB - Broken Data - Index Corrupt? - BSONObj Size

Tags: mongodb

I have a big problem with my MongoDB instance.

Every query I try to run (even simple ones, such as find( ) , count( ), etc.) I got this error:

```
exception: BSONObj size: 536871756 (0x2000034C) is invalid. Size must be between 0 and 16793600(16MB) First element: _id: ObjectId('5eaabac87fbaa8433bc16377')",
```

First, I can clarify that it always happens, so it does not depend on the complexity of the queries. By running the validate( ) function, I got this message:

```
"ns" : db.Message",
"datasize" : 259023456,
"nrecords" : 114778,
"lastExtentSize" : 92585984,
"firstExtent" : "0:5000 ns:db-2020.Message",
"lastExtent" : "4:4169000 ns:db-2020.Message",
"extentCount" : 14,
"firstExtentDetails" : {
"loc" : "0:5000",
"xnext" : "0:a9000",
"xprev" : "null",
"nsdiag" : "db-2020.Message",
"size" : 8192,
"firstRecord" : "0:68b0",
"lastRecord" : "0:68b0"
},
"lastExtentDetails" : {
"loc" : "4:4169000",
"xnext" : "null",
"xprev" : "4:2000",
"nsdiag" : "db-2020.Message",
"size" : 92585984,
"firstRecord" : "4:76d48b0",
"lastRecord" : "4:76d38b0"
},
"deletedCount" : 54891,
"deletedSize" : 597699520,
"nIndexes" : 0,
"keysPerIndex" : {
},
"valid" : false,
"errors" : [
"bad pointer in deleted record list: 536870914:2e46b0 bucket: 5 k: 54795"
],
"warning" : "Some checks omitted for speed. use {full:true} option to do more thorough scan.",
"advice" : "ns corrupt. See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/data-recovery",
"ok" : 1
```

So it seems something related to data storage and index corruption.

By using some GUIs I recovered around 11k rows (out of 115k contained in the files) but I still did not understand the problem (or the solution).

What I did:

- Mongoexport does not work (CSV, JSON, etc.) - When it reaches the
  broken data, it stops
- Mongodump (even with --repair and --forceTableScan) does not work reIndex( ) does not work - Indeed, no index is currently available in the DB
- deleteOne( ) and similar do not work. I tried to match the ID but nothing happens. I also tried
  to go through the data through a GUI but it stops when the broken data are reached.

Have you any other ideas? I would need to recover as much data as possible.

Grazie!

Comment: If you are a paying customer I suggest using official support channels. Otherwise rebuild the node or restore from backup.